# Convert MKV to AVI

Tags: file-conversion, video

What's the best solution to convert `.mkv` files to `.avi` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [Any Video Coverter](http://www.any-video-converter.com/products/mac_video_converter_freeware/) (Free Software)

[image]

Also you can [download and add codec](http://www.any-video-converter.com/products/for_mac/download-codec.php) for extra format like WMA and RealVideo.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to see this Videos on your Apple Mobile Devices (iPod Touch, iPhone or iPad) I would **strongly suggest** that you get your hands on **[Air Video](http://itunes.apple.com/app/air-video-watch-your-videos/id306550020?mt=8)**

Then, download and install in your Windows or Mac the [**free server** application](http://www.inmethod.com/air-video/download.html) and tell it to "see" all folders you have videos on.

[image]

you can now access from your mobile devices, all Videos ad if you have a good Dual Core 2 (or up) CPU in the machine you installed the "Server", you can see all videos with their "Live Conversion", in other words, you can **see them 5 seconds after you tap PLAY**, instead waiting for the conversion is ready.

pressing the Add to iTunes, it will convert and add to your iTunes list directly (if you want to see "offline" / not in the same WiFi as your server)

give it a try!

*examples:*

[image]

[image]

**P.S.** if you **only wish to convert videos and add them into your iTunes list**, just use the free Server Application, no need to have the AirVideo App, this is only required if you want to watch the videos on your devices.

Comment: How exactly can you convert file with server only?

Comment: you can't do that, btw the app is also free, though they have a paid one that I'm using...

Answer (score 0):

How about Quicktime 7 Pro?  Especially if you already have it...

Answer (score 0):

**[MPEG Streamclip](http://www.squared5.com/)**

My go-to application for all video conversion. I would highly recommend MPEG Streamclip. It should be able to handle what you want to do. And...it's free!